# Typescript returns errors in Redux types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Quick question, I'm writting a React-native application with typescript and redux. Running into error when trying to connect() and can't seem to find a solution to the error. I assume its something wrong I did but after looking at it for couple hours can't find a reason.

Error:

```
Argument of type '(state: AppStateType) => { user: AppStateType; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<IMapStateToProps, void, {}>'.
  Type '(state: AppStateType) => { user: AppStateType; }' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToProps<IMapStateToProps, void, {}>'.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AppStateType'.
        Property 'username' is missing in type '{}'.
```

When trying to connect(mapStateToProps):

```
export default connect<IMapStateToProps, Object, void>(*mapStateToProps*, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

My Reducer:

```
import * as Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';
// our defined @types
import { AppStateType, ActionType } from '../../@types';

const appState: AppStateType = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    serviceCode: 0,
    fetching: false
};

// enforce that state is immutable
export const initialState = Immutable.from(appState);

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionType)  => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_USER':
            state = {
                ...state,
                fetching: false
            };
        break;
        case 'SET_USER':
            state = {
                ...state,
                fetching: false
            };
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    return state;
};

export default userReducer;
```

@types file:

```
// app state type
export type AppStateType = {
    username: '';
    password: '';
    serviceCode: 0;
    fetching: false;
};

export interface InterfaceSetUser {
    type: 'SET_USER';
    payload?: {};
}

export interface InterfaceFetchUser {
    type: 'FETCH_USER';
    payload?: {};
}

export type ActionType = InterfaceSetUser | InterfaceFetchUser;
```

Actions:

```
import { Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

export function SetUser(user: Object) {
    return function(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_USER',
            payload: user
        });
    };
}
```

Component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { AppStateType, ActionType } from '../@types';
import { Dispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { SetUser } from './../redux/actions/user.actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

interface IMapStateToProps {
    username: '';
    password: '';
    serviceCode: 0;
    fetching: false;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppStateType) => ({
    user: state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        setUser: SetUser
    }, dispatch);
};


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Home Screen
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect<IMapStateToProps, Object, void>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

I'm relatively new to Typescript and Redux therefore can't wrap my head around the issue. Can you point me to the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mapStateToProps()` should be returning a type of `IMapStateToProps` i.e. it's expecting an object with the properties `username`, `password`, `serviceCode` and `fetching`. However you are returning an object from `mapStateToProps()` with just a single property, `user`.

That is answering the question you asked, however there are lots of issues with your code that I'm not sure you are aware about. For example, `AppStateType` and `IMapStateToProps` have strange definitions that I would expect to be:

```
export type AppStateType = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    serviceCode: number;
    fetching: boolean;
};
```

`HomeScreen` should extend something like `React.Component<IMapStateToProps & { setUser: () => void}>` or whatever the definition of `setUser` might be.

The type of `mapDispatchToProps` is `Object` in your `connect()`. This is not accurate as it is really an object with a `setUser` function.

Comment: Thanks this really explains a lot, starting to get an idea now :)